# Группировка в Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, gems

```
def index
  @q = Product.ransack(params[:q])
  @products = @q.result.group(:product_sizes)
end

def product_query_params
  params.permit(q: [:weight_lteq, :weight_gteq, :price_lteq, :price_gteq])
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_sizes
  has_one :image
end
```

`Product.last.product_sizes.last` представляет собой:

```
ProductSize id: 1242, name: "180 х 220 х 21 ", price: 59280, created_at: "2020-04-04 11:44:35", updated_at: "2020-04-04 11:44:35", product_id: 18
```

`Product.last` представляет собой:

```
Product id: 18, name: "Доктор A2 S1200", about: " ", weight: 100, guarantee: 24, height: 21, spring: nil, orthopedic: true, custom_size: true
```

Как в ранзаке объединить поля поиска, которые находятся в разных сущностях(объектах)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ransack умеет работать с ассоциациями из коробки. Вам нужно правильно назвать поля в форме, которую вы используете для фильтрации, чтобы в контроллер приходили параметры `product_sizes_price_lteq` и `product_sizes_price_gteq` вместо `price_lteq` и `price_gteq`

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли.

Comment: единственное примечание что работает фильтр не в симбиозе с двумя поисковыми полями, а в разнобой. Не подскажете почему?

Comment: @WWW1981 не совсем вас поняла. Наверное будет лучше задать новый вопрос и полностью описать проблему с примером на конкретных данных, в том числе добавить код формы и лог сервера.

Comment: если заполнить и :weight_lteq, :weight_gteq и product_sizes_price_lteq, product_sizes_price_gteq , фильтр отдает предпочтение фильтрации только :weight_lteq, :weight_gteq данных полей, а поля product_sizes_price_lteq, product_sizes_price_gteq он просто игнорит, как будто там никаких параметров и нет для поиска.